# Uniqueness of principle coordinates

Tags: vibrations

I am currently studying two-degree of freedom systems in mechanical vibrations. I understand that in general, the equations of motion corresponding to the two independent coordinates can be coupled.

http://web.itu.edu.tr/~gundes/2dof.pdf

The pdf above (on page 5) mentions the possibility of choosing certain coordinates that result in uncoupled equations of motions (calling them "principle coordinates". My question is:

For a given physical system do there exist more than one set of principle coordinates?

Comment: Yes, if there's degeneracy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate or refer a link?